# I'm getting the following error when building an app on Android Devices

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-android

| ERROR  | An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'localNSMap' of undefined
| ERROR  | Cannot read property 'localNSMap' of undefined

This is the error i'm getting only for Android devices and it terminates before building the app. iOS it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the details you've provided us, it seems like `localNSMap` property on the object you're trying to access is only iOS. Properties containing `NS` usually specify the NeXTSTEP framework which was developed for objective C that iOS is based on.

Before you access that property check if the object is null/undefined. It seems that you're trying to access iOS specific variable.